# jQuery Dynamic form not posting on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, laravel

I am trying to create a form dynamically and then submitting it. I have it working on desktop browsers but on mobile Android and iOS, it does not work.

What it is doing is refreshing the page and not sending the post request.

Here is the code:

```
var $form = $(document.createElement('form')).attr('action', '/results').attr('method', 'POST');
$form.append(form.find('input[name="_token"]'));
$form.append('<input type="hidden" name="term" value="'+term+'">');
$form.append('<input type="hidden" name="extra" value="'+extra+'">');
$form.append('<input type="hidden" name="value" value="'+value+'">');
$form.append('<button id="submitSearch" type="submit"></button>');
$($form).appendTo(document.body);
$($form).submit();
```

Any ideas on why it would not work on mobile browsers?

Comment: if its laravel form should have a {{ csrf_field() }}. Do you have it on your form?

Comment: I did, however, it did not like it. I have had to place the form inside the page and then just append the fields.

Comment: as far as i know u need to put csrf_field in your form. Okey lets make it this way. inside your blade.php open script tag and write this:
`var token = {{ csrf_field() }};`
this one should come before your form append. and then append your form this:
`$form.append(token);`
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be an issue with Laravel not seeing the token correctly.

I created the form in the page and set the fields in the JS. This then seemed to work.